# NamedPipeClientStream - no way to cancel Connect

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I'd like to use `NamedPipeClientStream`:

```
var _Pipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "test-a", PipeDirection.In);
_Pipe.Connect();
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to pass Cancellation token. So, how to cancel connection? I don't want to pass timeout - my client needs to wait "forever" until connection is successful or cancel is requested. `ConnectAsync`is not available.

**EDIT:**
I am using .NET Frameowkr 4.5.2 Class library, and there is no such a method like ConnectAsync (only Connect is available).

Comment: Why is `ConnectAsync` not available? It's exactly the right tool to use here.

Comment: Do not know. I am using Framework 4.5.2 Class Library and there is no such a method.

Comment: I don't think there's any OS version that supports 4.5.2 but doesn't support 4.6. `CancelAsync` was added in 4.6

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are right. But we have an agreement with a client and we need to build our solution based on 4.5.2 framework.

Comment: Then you have conflicting requirements. You have one requirement that the connect by cancellable, *and* we know that cancellation support was explicitly added in 4.6, and you have another requirement to stay on 4.5.2. Ask someone (e.g. project manager, client, etc) to help to resolve the conflict, rather than expecting a technical fix.

Comment: But I don't believe that before 4.5.2 that problem was unresolveable. Changing things like OS/Framework version in corporate, isolated environment is not so easy as it may looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cancel, call Close() or Dispose() method on that pipe. If you'll need to retry later, just create another pipe for that.

I’m 90% sure the thread that was sleeping on that Connect() call will wake up immediately, and fail with some exception. Probably ObjectDisposedException if you call Dispose, or some "The pipe is being closed." Win32 exception if you call Close().

I have never tested with pipes specifically, but that’s what usually happens in Windows with blocking I/O calls for files and sockets.

Comment: Ohh, definitely worth trying. Thanks for hint!

Comment: Note that on .NET 3.5 Close/Dispose does NOT appear to cause Connect(int timeout) to unblock or throw. Sad times.